# RavenDB export / import data between RavenDB servers with Raven.Smuggler

Tags: ravendb, lucene.net, data-migration

I'm trying to export data with Raven.smuggler from one RavenDB server of **version 1.0**
and import it to other RavenDB server of **version 2.0**

I'm getting file load exception, due to lucene.net **version differences.**

Is it possible to migrate data from one version of RavenDB to another?
what is the best way to do it?

I've already read the following url:
http://ravendb.net/docs/server/administration/export-import

thanks for you help :-)

EDIT:
"unhandled Exceptions: system.net.webException: Error: System.IO.FileLoadException: could not load file or assembly 'Lucene.Net, Version=2.9.4.1.....' or one of its dependencies.

The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference..."

In the older version of Raven i was using Lucene Analyzer 2.9, which not exists in the new version. I'm guessing that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely move data between versions using smuggler.
Please post the full error you are seeing. Including stack trace.

Comment: sorry for not posting the full stack trace. development and internet environments are separated.